# How do I alter the entity type class?

Tags: 8, entities

In Drupal 8 you can load an entity with:

```
$node = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('node')->load(123);
```

This looks for the entity definitions and finds that *node* is defined by *Drupal\node\Entity\Node* - so (I guess) *Drupal\node\NodeStorage* will instantiate a new *Drupal\node\Entity\Node* instance.

What I'd like to achieve is subclassing *Drupal\node\Entity\Node* and being able to instantiate this subclass when it's appropriate. For example if I have a node bundle article, there would be a class:

```
namespace Drupal\my_module\Entity\Article;
class Article extends Drupal\node\Entity\Node {
}
```

And I'd call:

```
$node = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('node_article')->load(123);
```

And the return would be my `Article` subclass.

I can achieve this by creating a new entity type and wiring it back to another existing entity definitions, for example the node-article example would be this class:

```
namespace Drupal\my_module\Entity;
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
/**
 * @ContentEntityType(
 *   id = "node_article",
 *   label = @Translation("Content"),
 *   bundle_label = @Translation("Content type"),
 *   handlers = {
 *     "storage" = "Drupal\node\NodeStorage",
 *     "storage_schema" = "Drupal\node\NodeStorageSchema",
 *     "view_builder" = "Drupal\node\NodeViewBuilder",
 *     "access" = "Drupal\node\NodeAccessControlHandler",
 *     "views_data" = "Drupal\node\NodeViewsData",
 *     "form" = {
 *       "default" = "Drupal\node\NodeForm",
 *       "delete" = "Drupal\node\Form\NodeDeleteForm",
 *       "edit" = "Drupal\node\NodeForm"
 *     },
 *     "route_provider" = {
 *       "html" = "Drupal\node\Entity\NodeRouteProvider",
 *     },
 *     "list_builder" = "Drupal\node\NodeListBuilder",
 *     "translation" = "Drupal\node\NodeTranslationHandler"
 *   },
 *   base_table = "node",
 *   data_table = "node_field_data",
 *   revision_table = "node_revision",
 *   revision_data_table = "node_field_revision",
 *   translatable = TRUE,
 *   list_cache_contexts = { "user.node_grants:view" },
 *   entity_keys = {
 *     "id" = "nid",
 *     "revision" = "vid",
 *     "bundle" = "type",
 *     "label" = "title",
 *     "langcode" = "langcode",
 *     "uuid" = "uuid",
 *     "status" = "status",
 *     "uid" = "uid",
 *   },
 *   bundle_entity_type = "node_type",
 *   field_ui_base_route = "entity.node_type.edit_form",
 *   common_reference_target = TRUE,
 *   permission_granularity = "bundle",
 *   links = {
 *     "canonical" = "/node/{node}",
 *     "delete-form" = "/node/{node}/delete",
 *     "edit-form" = "/node/{node}/edit",
 *     "version-history" = "/node/{node}/revisions",
 *     "revision" = "/node/{node}/revisions/{node_revision}/view",
 *   }
 * )
 */
class Article extends Node { }

// Results my Article sub type.
$node = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('node_article')->load(123);
```

This works fine (as much as I can see); however, it smells. It adds a new entity type, which is not true, and might cause other troubles in the future.

How do I define a subclass for an entity bundle so that loading the entity would return an object of that class?

Comment: I'm not sure you can provide a different entity class per bundle; you can use `hook_entity_type_alter()` to make the change more cleanly, but I don't know how you'd limit that to a specific bundle

Comment: Thank you Clive - that looks a promising hook to investigate!

Answer (score 16):

Create a new class in your module that extends `\Drupal\node\Entity\Node`.

```
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node as BaseNode;

class MyNode extends BaseNode {
}
```

Implement [`hook_entity_type_build()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_type_build/8.2.x).

```
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface;

/**
 * @param EntityTypeInterface[] $entity_types
 */
function my_module_entity_type_build(&$entity_types) {
  if (isset($entity_types['node'])) {
    $entity_types['node']->setClass('Drupal\my_module\Entity\MyNode');
  }
}
```

Remember to rebuild the cache.

It works fine when loading nodes via the entity type manager service and the node storage. It even works when you just use `Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($nid)` thanks to the fact that this `load()` function it is just a static wrapper for the entity type manager service call provided by the `Entity` class which is extended from the `Node` class.

```
// Part of Entity class for reference
abstract class Entity implements EntityInterface {
  /**
   * Loads an entity.
   *
   * @param mixed $id
   *   The id of the entity to load.
   *
   * @return static
   *   The entity object or NULL if there is no entity with the given ID.
   */
  public static function load($id) {
    $entity_manager = \Drupal::entityManager();
    return $entity_manager->getStorage($entity_manager->getEntityTypeFromClass(get_called_class()))->load($id);
  }
}
```

This also works fine with the soon-to-be-removed `entity_load_multiple()` function, so I guess this covers all standard use cases for loading nodes.

Of course, if your module does this and another module does the same, you'll have a problem, but I guess it's not common scenario, and it makes sense only for very specific use cases.

Comment: Sorry but no :) The question was to have a different class per *bundle*. You're changing the class for all bundles of the entity type node. That's not the same.

Comment: @Berdir, your right :( ... Having classes per bundle means that a entity storage for node would have to be extended too so that it's load methods could be overridden to produce those per bundle classes. Which basically is one huge headache.

Comment: Yeah. https://www.drupal.org/node/2570593 is one of the issues that I referenced but forgot to actually link to in my answer.

Comment: I have implemented hook_entity_type_alter to set custom class. It works too.

Comment: When I attempt this method I get a 'Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The "node" entity type does not exist.' message. I'm using the ablecore_entity_type_build function in my .module file. And I have my AbleNode.php in /src/Entity/AbleNode/ folder

Comment: Nevermind I got it. I needed to put it in Plugins/Node

Answer (score 5):

From Drupal 9.3, there is support for [entity bundle classes included in core.](https://www.drupal.org/node/3191609)

So now you can subclass your entity bundles as much as you like without needing any contrib modules.

The core change record is extensive, but basically this:

```
use Drupal\mymodule\Entity\BasicPage;

function mymodule_entity_bundle_info_alter(array &$bundles): void {
  if (isset($bundles['node']['page'])) {
    $bundles['node']['page']['class'] = BasicPage::class;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the right answer since 9.3.

Answer (score 3):

I experienced the same issue and decided to create a module that alter the entity type class of Drupal entities via the plugin system. Currently it supports altering the `Node`, `User` and `File` entity classes. When altering the `Node` entitiy you are able to alter the type class per node bundle.

Check out the module description for an example:

https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_type_class

The module uses [hook_entity_type_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_type_alter/8.3.x) to set a handler class on entities that you provide in your plugin annotation.

Answer (score 3):

This module also gives you real bundle classes - https://github.com/amcgowanca/discoverable_entity_bundle_classes

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but the real answer should be:

If you need different behaviour across bundles, then you should be using different entity types, not different bundles.

Custom Content Entities are 1st class citizens in D8.  In fact we estimate that it takes about 30 minutes to get a new custom content entity to the level that node is (which really just comes down to adding the Form UI to get the nice side panel, and the alias/revision fields.)  This doesn't include adding the translation pages, but that isn't that much more.

If you haven't seen it, take a look at the Drupal Console's generate:custom:entity features.