# How to check if an article is referenced from a collection?

Tags: 8, entities

I have a `collection` content type which is just a list of `EntityReferences` to articles.

When I am loading an `article`, how can I use the `Entity API` to check if it belongs to one or more collections?

Previously I would query the `DB`, but I wonder if there is a more idiomatic way?

Comment: If you do not know all fields that might be referencing this entity type then I doubt you can get that information with entity query. One thing that comes to mind is to load all entity reference fields, filter out those that do not allow your entity to be referenced and then construct entity query accordingly to match those fields and entity types they are attached to.

Comment: Thanks @IvanJaros for your comment. My use case is not that complex, There is only one field that references the articles so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load all collection id's, which have a reference to $article_id:

```
$collection_ids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
  ->condition('type', 'collection')
  ->condition('field_article_ref', $article_id)
  ->execute();
if ( count($collection_ids) > 0 ) {
  echo "the article $article_id is referenced in one or more collections";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Nice and simple.What would be the right way to encapsulate this method? I would like to be able to do something like `$article->collections()` but that is maybe [a different question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/173922/what-is-the-best-way-to-extend-drupal-node-entity-node)