# How do I find "where-used" / many-to-one related entities?

Tags: 8, entities

A field in my *Content Type A* references a *Content Type B*.

I'd like to find, in each instance of *Content Type B*, a list of all the *A*s that reference it at a particular point in time.

[Update]:
I made the question less ambiguous in the light of the answer I found with help from others here.

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/184397/how-to-check-if-an-article-is-referenced-from-a-collection#comment223326_184397

Comment: Thanks Ivan. Can't see how to embed the query in the display / newsletter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is in my `agenda.module`. The *where-used* relation is used as follows in the form validation handler that is called when the user clicks the *Delete* button on  the  delete  confirmation form:

The *Agenda* Node cannot be deleted if there are any *Meeting* Nodes that refer to it.

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

function agenda_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    // ...
    case "node_agenda_delete_form":
      $form['#validate'][] = '_agenda_delete_validation';
      break;
    // ...
  }
}

function _agenda_delete_validation(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $agenda_node = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();
  $agenda_name = $agenda_node->getTitle();
  $agenda_node_id = $agenda_node->id();
  $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
    ->condition('type', 'meeting')
    ->condition('field_agenda', $agenda_node_id);
  $nids = $query->execute();
  $count_nids = count($nids);
  if ($count_nids > 0) {
    $msg_stem = ($count_nids == 1) ? 'There is one Meeting that references "' : 'There are '.$count_nids.' Meetings that reference "';
    $form_state->setError($form, $msg_stem.$agenda_name.'". It cannot be deleted yet.' );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a quick solution in code, you can use the same way as in drupal 7:

Add a field (configurable in view modes):

[hook_entity_extra_field_info](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_extra_field_info/8)

Put the code for the field in here:

[hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view/8)

Use this code:

[How to check if an article is referenced from a collection?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/184397/how-to-check-if-an-article-is-referenced-from-a-collection#comment223326_184397)

Comment: V useful. Will experiment with this.

Comment: I used the code you referred to (item 3) in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In D7, Entity Views Attachment was the most popular solution for this. It has no D8 port yet however.

D8 modules which offer this functionality include:

- Display Suite. It enables you to add a view as a dynamic field; that view could use a contextual filter to focus its content on the current node URL.
- Viewfield, as you suggested. You use a token to specify a default view, and choose to "force the default" to prevent content editors from changing the selected view.
- [Display fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/display_fields), an interesting new D8 module. It allows you to place views as fields on a node, and is meant to allow contextual arguments, but I've not been able to set this up properly (see the [issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2639296))

Comment: V useful. Will experiment with *Display fields* too. The *Embed a view* variant sounds ideal.

Comment: I've just tried Display fields views embedding and been unsuccessful, I've edited my answer to mention. Please accept if you're happy with the answer.