# Can you add methods to node-entities?

Tags: 7, entities

What is the preferred way to add functionality to nodes? 
More explicitly stated: What is the node-entity equivalent of the Entity-class from the entity-API-module?

Sometimes you want to add methods to a entity. That is possible when using the entity-module, where each entity has a "entity class" property. You can take this entity class and extend it to your heart's content.

However, this is not possible with node-entities, since these don't use the "entity class" attribute.

So, the following code would work if drupal-core worked like the entity-module, but throws an error as is:

```
function myNode_entity_info_alter(&$info){
    $info['node']['entity class'] = 'MyNode';
}

class MyNode extends Entity{
    public function sayHi(){
        drupal_set_message("Hi!");
    }
}


function myNode_entity_load($entities, $type){
    if($type == 'node'){
        foreach ($entities as $entity) {
            $entity->sayHi(); # Error: Call to undefined method stdClass::sayHi()
        }
    }
}
```

How can I make this work with node-entities?

PS: as a follow-up question: is this any easier using drupal8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I have found something that does what I want: https://www.deeson.co.uk/labs/extending-entitydrupalwrapper

The basic idea is that, since drupal-core doesn't facilitate the extension of entity-classes, we use the entity-metadata-wrapper instead.

The above example would then be reformulated as such:

```
class MyNodeWrapper extends EntityDrupalWrapper{
    public function __construct($data) {
        parent::__construct('node', $data);
    }

    public function sayHi(){
        drupal_set_message("Hi!");
    }
}

function myNode_entity_load($entities, $type){
    if($type == 'node'){
        foreach ($entities as $entity) {
            $emw = new MyNodeWrapper($entity);
            $emw ->sayHi();
        }
    }
}
```

This appears to be a very reasonable approach. Only thing I dislike about it is that you can't use `entity_metadata_wrapper` to get the MyNodeWrapper-wrapper.

Comment: Is this possible in D8?

Comment: @drupality : [this question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/173922/what-is-the-best-way-to-extend-drupal-node-entity-node) seems to deal with the same problem from a drupal8 perspective. It appears that directly extending a node-class is still not the canonical approach, but quite possible, according to SiliconMind 's answer. There is also a more in-depth answer [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/173811/how-to-alter-the-entity-type-class-in-drupal-8/199395#199395) . However, this way you extend the whole node class - I'm not sure if you can do this bundle-specific.

Comment: @drupality: as for extending the EntityMetadataWrapper instead of the node-class: it seems drupal8 has dropped EMW's and instead integrated them into the entity-classes themselves; thus making it unnecessary to first fetch an object and then wrap it in a EMW.