# How can I alter the node title in every display?

Tags: 8, nodes

I have a content type "Campus", I would like to concat to the title "*Campus name* **campus**". So, there is a hook or something to alter the node getTitle() method in every display?

I've tested:

- preprocess_node
- preprocess_page
- views_pre_build
- views_pre_render
- entity_view_alter
- preprocess_field__title
- preprocess_page_title

preprocess_field example code:

```
function usc_theme_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
  if (!empty($variables['element'])) {
    $field = $variables['element'];
    if ($field['#bundle'] === 'campus' && $field['#field_name'] === 'title') {
      /** @var \Drupal\node\Entity\Node $entity */
      $field[0]['#context']['value'] = 'popopo';
      /** @var \Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemList $list */
      $list = $field['#items'];
      $val  = $list->getValue()[0]['value'];

      $field['#items']      = $list->setValue('testttttt');
      $variables['element'] = $field;

      $entity                          = $variables['element']['#object'];
      $entity->title                   = 'aaa';
      $variables['element']['#object'] = $entity;
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks all for help.

Comment: There’s no hook, but you can subclass the node entity class and override the `getTitle`, `label()`, etc methods.

Comment: Can you share your code that you tried

Comment: Hmm, i'm gonna try to extend node and alter getTitle(), thanks!

Comment: PD: Editing the question to add the last test i've did.

Comment: Well, I can't extend Node class, cause my content type exists already...

Comment: take a look https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/173811/how-do-i-alter-the-entity-type-class/199395#199395