# Add status field to existing entity

Tags: 8

I wanted to add the "status" field to an entity that already exists but is not mine, i.e. I cannot edit the php class where this entity is defined.

With the following code I add the field in database, but I don't have access to the "isPublished()" or "setPublished()" methods, because for that **the entity should implement the** "**EntityPublishedTrait**" trait.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_install().
 */
function project_groups_access_install($is_syncing) {
  $definition_update_manager = \Drupal::entityDefinitionUpdateManager();
  $entity_type               = $definition_update_manager->getEntityType('my_entity');

  // Bail out early if a field named 'status' is already installed.
  if ($definition_update_manager->getFieldStorageDefinition('status', 'my_entity')) {
    return t('The publishing status field has <strong>not</strong> been added to my_entity.');
  }

  // Add the 'published' entity key to the my_entity entity type.
  $entity_keys              = $entity_type->getKeys();
  $entity_keys['published'] = 'status';
  $entity_type->set('entity_keys', $entity_keys);
  $definition_update_manager->updateEntityType($entity_type);

  // Add the status field.
  $status = BaseFieldDefinition::create('boolean')
    ->setLabel(t('Published'))
    ->setDescription(t('A boolean indicating the published state.'))
    ->setRevisionable(TRUE)
    ->setTranslatable(TRUE)
    ->setDefaultValue(TRUE)
    ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
      'type'     => 'boolean_checkbox',
      'settings' => [
        'display_label' => TRUE,
        'default_value' => TRUE,
      ],
      'weight'   => 120,
    ])
    ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE);

  $status->setInitialValue(TRUE);
  $definition_update_manager->installFieldStorageDefinition('status', 'group', 'group', $status);

  return t('The published field has been added to groups.');
}
```

My question is: **how can I make that entity implement the EntityPublishedTrait class to have access to those methods**?

Comment: If you can't edit the php class you have to extend it in your own module. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/199395/47547

Comment: Okay, I understand. I had tried it but with the hook "hook_entity_type_alter". Now it looks better, thank you very much!